# Define dynamic id in html

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to define id into array ? how can we add text in this
id using the jquery?

```
> <ul> <li><div class="artistName"></div></li> <li><div
> class="artistName"></div></li> <li><div class="artistName"></div></li>
> <li><div class="artistName"></div></li> <li><div
> class="artistName"></div></li> </ul>


$("#fap-playlist li").each(function(){        
    $('#artistName'+[n]).html(getSongID);     
});
```

I want to add different text in "artistName" class according to li

Comment: your question is not clear, can you please post fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/

Comment: Please: read your question again and then ask yourself: "if this is all I know about the problem, do I understand what the problem is?" Because I, having read it, have *no idea* what you want us to help with. Or what help you need. Please provide an [MCVE representation of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/), and *clearly explain the problem you're facing.*

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, just adjust your example like this:

```
$("#fap-playlist li").each(function( index ) {
 $('#artistName'+ index ).html(getSongID);
});
```

For reference of jQuery each(), just have a look at the jQuery api doc for [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
In case this is not what you're looking for, please adjust your question as it's not clear what you want to have as result and you only provided part of your code. Just taking a guess that you want to iterate over several `$("#fap-playlist li")`.

Update: As question was adjusted multiple times - current question to add a class with a name based on position of the li with class "artistName", this could work:

```
$(".artistName").each(function( index ) {
 $(this).addClass("newClass" + index);
});
```

And In case the question is to add text inside the li, it'd be:

```
 $(".artistName").each(function( index ) {
  $(this).text("Number: " + index);
 });
```